# Customizing two columns with colored headers

Tags: color, multicol

Multicolumn package can be used two organize content in two columns. For example:

[image]

- How can set up a diluted background color to the headers?(it would be good if they are centered also)

Here I provide a MWE for suggestions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\addtolength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\underline{nifurtimox}

Comercialmente distribuido como Lampit\textsuperscript{\textregistered}, desarrollado en 1960 por el laboratorio X.\\[0.5cm]
%\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{nifurt.pdf}

\columnbreak

\underline{benznidazol}

Conocido comercialmente como Rochagan\textsuperscript{\textregistered} o Radanil\textsuperscript{\textregistered}. Lanzado al mercado en 1971 por el laboratorio Y.\\[0.3em]
   % \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{bzn.pdf]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Any help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with `xcolor`s `\colorbox` and `\makebox`.

The code below colors the complete line. If you only want the name of the chemical to be colored, comment out the line `\noindent\colorbox...` and uncomment the line `\noindent\makebox...`. If you want additional space between the headline and the text, uncomment the line `\par\vspace{1ex}%` and adjust the space to your liking. And with `\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}` you can increase the size of the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\addtolength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\ChemName}[1]{%
    % complete line colored
    \noindent\colorbox{yellow!50}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{#1}}%
    % just the name colored
    %\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\colorbox{yellow!50}{#1}}%
    % to add some space between headline and text
    %\par\vspace{1ex}%
}
% to increase size of colored box
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ChemName{nifurtimox}

Comercialmente distribuido como Lampit\textsuperscript{\textregistered}, desarrollado en 1960 por el laboratorio X.\\[0.5cm]
%\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{nifurt.pdf}

\columnbreak

\ChemName{benznidazol}

Conocido comercialmente como Rochagan\textsuperscript{\textregistered} o Radanil\textsuperscript{\textregistered}. Lanzado al mercado en 1971 por el laboratorio Y.\\[0.3em]
   % \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{bzn.pdf]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

With the code above:

[image]

And with `\noindent\makebox...`

[image]

Comment: wowwww. +1 and accepted.